# Is it possible to download Android SDK components without using the Android SDK management utility?

Tags: sockets, android, installation, buffer-overflow, connection

During the installation of my Android SDK, I am getting stuck during the process where the manager goes out and downloads all the revisions of the APIs and the SDKs.

It is potentially due to a socket issue that typically occurs when a database query is called and there are a large number of TCP connections... according to googling my error (No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed )...

So I just need to know if there is a way, other then using the Android download manager, to download / update my computer with the following Android SDK components:

> Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 7, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Skipping 'Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 7, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK  Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 1' which was not installed.
>   Downloading Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 7, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Skipping 'Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 6, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK  Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1' which was not installed.
>   Downloading Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 6, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Skipping 'Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 5, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1' which was not installed.
>   Downloading Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 5, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 2
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Skipping 'Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 4, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK  Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 2' which was not installed.
>   Downloading Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 4, revision 2
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 3
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Skipping 'Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 3, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK  Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 3' which was not installed.
>   Downloading Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 3, revision 3
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.1, API 2, revision 1
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed
>   Downloading Usb Driver package, revision 3
>   No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): recv failed

Thank you.

Comment: [Screenshots] Available packages for download: http://i45.tinypic.com/9igs48.jpg

--

Installation errors: http://i50.tinypic.com/260fxox.jpg

Answer (score 0):

switch to HTTP and see if you still have the problem..manually launch from command line than left top click to get settings menu

Comment: Thanks Fred.
I already had the setting switched to HTTP.

Can you expand on your next statement.
"manually launch from command line then left top click to get settings menu"

thank you